# How to include and use new fonts in win32 project.?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I have downloaded new ttf font. And I want to use that font in my win32 project.
How to include and use new fonts in my project.?

Comment: Do you mean so its selectable in a forms/dialog designer? how to load it for use with gdi? or how to install/include it with your application? how to make a font resource?

Answer (score 4):

Add the font as resource, load the resource, then use `AddFontMemResourceEx` API:

> This function allows an application to get a font that is embedded in a document or a webpage. A font that is added by AddFontMemResourceEx is always private to the process that made the call and is not enumerable.

You can find example code in [this codeguru article](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/fonts/print.php/c16019).

Comment: ya..its useful.. but i need a simple example just to display a text " hello World" with the font ttf I have downloaded. And I am also using wxWidgets.